# Is it reasonable to ask developers to specify exception type?

Tags: manual-testing, exception

I am testing a Customer Relationship Management software package. I noticed that when a certain critical error occurs, an exception message will pop up but this exception message will only state:

- Unhandled exception, following by technical details.

I want to raise an issue to developers, requesting this critical exception to be handled properly and a proper message should be displayed.

An unhandled exception does not provide any useful information to a user or a developer.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stack Trace in the unhandled exception message should tell the developer what crashed and when. Your provided Steps to Reproduce should also help pin down the issue (a developer can't fix what they can't reproduce). In that case the exception should be fixed and/or handled better in future releases. Just report it like any other bug.